# How to fix dark mode not changing text colors if css variable declared

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to make a dark / light mode on my website, which I am struggling with, but some of the text isn't changing colors, specifically only the ones where there is a css property in the head's style.

[You can see the issue on this w3schools page.](https://yealet.w3spaces.com/darkmode.html)
Edit, code below, thought it showed on the w3schools page, I apologize.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("light-mode");
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

h5 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

body {
  background-color: #424447;
  margin: 0;
}

.light-mode {
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  color: black;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #2e3033;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid #65676b;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  text-align: center
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.navbar li {
  float: center;
}

.navbar a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white
}

.navbar a:link,
.navbar a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar a:active {
  background-color: #373b44;
}

.homepage {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.motivepage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 7.5px;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
  border: 4px solid #65676b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #56585b;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="google.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="google.com">Motives</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="homepage" id="homepage">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" style="float: right; height: 20px; width: 19%; margin: 5px; background-color: whitesmokel; border: 0px solid white; border-radius: 8px;">
    Toggle Light Mode
  </button>

  <h1>Home</h1>

  <h3>
    We look to bring you powerful, empowering, and inspirational motives that will help push you further through life.
  </h3>
</div>

<div class="motivepage" style="float: left;">
  <h2 style="margin-left: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    xxx
  </h2>
  <h4 style="margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    xxx
  </h4>
  <h5 style="margin-left: 8px;">
    xxx
  </h5>
</div>

<div class="motivepage" style="float: right">
  <h2 style="margin-left: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    xxx
  </h2>
  <h4 style="margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    xxx
  </h4>
  <h5 style="margin-left: 8px;">
    xxx
  </h5>
</div>
```

I am not sure as of where to go to try and fix this really, although I did attempt to find out how to change the text color but to be honest, I really just don't know how to do that, I am a beginner.

I want to accomplish where you can click the button, the background turns a light shade of grey, the text turns black, and the other mini boxes below become a white.
[Almost as shown on the w3schools demo.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_dark_mode)

Comment: Please note that [providing a link to your site is not sufficient](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to target the other elements. And the end of your CSS, I would simply use **.light-mode element{}**.

This will give you more control on an element by element basis in case you actually want to do more.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("light-mode");
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

h5 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

body {
  background-color: #424447;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #2e3033;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid #65676b;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  text-align: center
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.navbar li {
  float: center;
}

.navbar a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white
}

.navbar a:link,
.navbar a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar a:active {
  background-color: #373b44;
}

.homepage {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.motivepage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 7.5px;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
  border: 4px solid #65676b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #56585b;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.light-mode {
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

.light-mode .motivepage{
  background:#fff;
}

.light-mode .motivepage,
.light-mode h1,
.light-mode h3{
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="google.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="google.com">Motives</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="homepage" id="homepage">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" style="float: right; height: 20px; width: 19%; margin: 5px; background-color: whitesmokel; border: 0px solid white; border-radius: 8px;">
    Toggle Light Mode
  </button>

  <h1>Home</h1>

  <h3>
    We look to bring you powerful, empowering, and inspirational motives that will help push you further through life.
  </h3>
</div>

<div class="motivepage" style="float: left;">
  <h2 style="margin-left: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    xxx
  </h2>
  <h4 style="margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    xxx
  </h4>
  <h5 style="margin-left: 8px;">
    xxx
  </h5>
</div>

<div class="motivepage" style="float: right">
  <h2 style="margin-left: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    xxx
  </h2>
  <h4 style="margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    xxx
  </h4>
  <h5 style="margin-left: 8px;">
    xxx
  </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked very well and it does help with the customization on the specific sections as well, thank you so much.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.light-mode` text color is being overridden by the `.homepage` color, which has higher specificity here. You can fix this by adding more specificity with the * selector (or another selector of your choice):

After the light-mode selector, add:

```
.light-mode * {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: This did work mostly, but it keeps the 'motivepage' div's still grey, I tried to fix it with adding a second element in the function but it didnt work VV

var element2 = document.motivepage;
\element2.classList.toggle("light-mode");

Comment: @yealet If you want the motivepage div background-color to be white in light mode, you can add `.light-mode .motivepage { background-color: white}`. The same applies for the border.

Comment: That selector won't work because 1) h1 is an element, not a class 2) the h1 is not a descendant of .motivepage. This will achieve your goal: `.light-mode .homepage h1 { color: #0f4fe5; }`